# Converting to unicode font in Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2005

I want to convert Report Headers and Section Headers to Hindi unicode font. At present I am using a Hindi font which is not rendering properly on various browsers. Is there any way to convert the Report Header and other fonts to unicode in Crystal Reports 2005?

Comment: I don't totally understand what you're trying to accomplish, so I'm sorry if this is an obvious suggestion. Look at the individual fields and text areas, and try selecting a different font. Sections themselves don't have fonts, only fields.

Comment: @noa Let me clarify. Most Asian language fonts don't render properly on browsers. One of them are Hindi language font like 'Arjun'. I want to know whether there is any way in Crystal Reports to convert the font to unicode equivalent?

Comment: Does the font render correctly in the report designer?

Comment: @noa Yes it renders fine in report designer but browsers are giving different looks. Extra spaces are added in between characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by Crystal Reports 2005 you mean the version of CR that bundles with .NET 2005, then you want to look at the following;

1. [Working with Default and Custom Language Resource Files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227600%28VS.80%29.aspx)
2. [Compiling the Custom Resource Files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227633%28v=VS.80%29.aspx)
3. [Web: Configuring Global or Local Custom Resources](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227574%28v=VS.80%29.aspx)

You also want make sure you are using SP 1 for CR 10.2:

https://smpdl.sap-ag.de/~sapidp/012002523100006007872008E/crvs05sp1.exe

Note that new, stand alone version(s) of CR have better localization support. Looking at CR 2008 (12.x) may be something to consider. An Eval of CR 2008 is available here:

http://www.sap.com/solutions/sapbusinessobjects/sme/freetrials/index.epx

Hope this will help !

Comment: What are the major improvements in crcs05sp1?

Comment: Its hard to list the changes of earlier versions of CR, to my knowledge, there is not one page where you could go and find all info on a per SP. [Here is a list](http://resources.businessobjects.com/support/communitycs/FilesAndUpdates/cr_net_2005_mergemodule_readme.pdf) with major fixes in the SP.